# Android fragment replacement

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment called ProjectsFragment, that has a constraintLayout, recyclerView and a FloatingActionButton.

I'm trying to make it when I click the button to go to another fragment.

The new fragment is called NewProjectFragment.

The code that I've got so far is below but it's not being replaced. I know the code is being ran as the log is printed

```
FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NewProjectFragment npf = new NewProjectFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.constraintLayout, npf);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

            Log.d("swap", "swap");
        }
    });
```

The tabs are setup using the below on the MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

The SimpleFragmentPageAdapter is below

```
public class SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    // This determines the fragment for each tab
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new ProjectsFragment();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new ColoursFragment();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return new WishListFragment();
        } else if (position == 3) {
            return new AboutFragment();
        } else {
            return new ProjectsFragment();
        }
    }

    // This determines the number of tabs
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    // This determines the title for each tab
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.project_tab);
            case 1:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.colours_tab);
            case 2:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.wish_list_tab);
            case 3:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.about_tab);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

The ActivityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the fragment_projects.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.ProjectsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout" >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> transaction.replace(R.id.constraintLayout, npf);

Looks like you're trying to replace into a constraint layout, which smells funny to me. Usually you have a FrameLayout that is a simple container for the fragments. Thus, my guess would be that you are moving the new fragment into the existing fragment's layout, without constraints, so it's not showing up and the first one remains in place.

Make sure you're using the ID of the view in the layout that contains the first fragment (again, usually a FrameLayout in the owning Actvity layout).

If that is not your issue, post your XML file.

---

**Update.**

Yeah, as I guessed, you're replacing into a ConstraintLayout and that's not a good idea, as you've seen. Your setup is  a bit weird because you have a ViewPager that is managing one set of fragments and you want to push a new one over everything?

I'd suggest you just launch a new Activity instead.

Comment: I'm just editing the default one that comes when you create a new tabbed project, I've included the xml files above